# NullPointerException в родительском классе, можно ли переопределить методом, генерирующим RuntimeException?

Tags: java

В случае, когда метод генерирует исключение NullPointerException в родительском классе, можно ли его переопределить методом, генерирующим RuntimeException?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да. Это легко проверить создав два класса:

```
class Parent {
    void method() throws NullPointerException {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void method() throws RuntimeException {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

и вызвав метод:

```
try {
    new Child().method();
} catch(RuntimeException re) {
    System.out.println("YEAH");
}
```

Стоит заметить, что `RuntimeException` и его наследники называются непроверяемыми исключениями. Их можно выбрасывать и без объявления.

```
void method() {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

Объявление непроверяемого исключения несет чисто информационный характер и никак не влияет на возможность переопределения метода в классах наследниках.

На возможность переопределения метода может повлиять только проверяемое исключение. По спецификации ([JLS§8.4.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3)) ошибкой считается объявление в классе-наследнике проверяемых исключений, которые не объявлены в классе родителе.

Например, попытка при переопределении объявить `IOException` приведет к ошибке компиляции.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    void method() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```